# Upload doesn't work: mail form with upload image to the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to have a mail for which sends 1) a mail and 2) when press the submit button also upload a file to the server.

My problem now is on point 2. the mail form works already. I use ajax and PHP for it. When I press submit the mail is sending but nothing is uploading to my directory. I don't get any errors.. does somebody have an idea?

```
<?php
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

$currentDir = getcwd();
$uploadDirectory = "uploads/";

$errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

$fileExtensions = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']; // Get all the file extensions

$fileName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
$fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $fileName)));

$uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!in_array($fileExtension, $fileExtensions)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file";
    }

    if ($fileSize > 2000000) {
        $errors[] = "This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be less than or equal to 2MB";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
            echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
            echo "An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin";
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
    }
}

$from = '';
$sendTo = '';
$Bcc = '';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'Neue Nachricht von ';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('firma' => 'Firma', 'anrede' => 'Anrede', 'vorname' => 'Vorname', 'nachname' => 'Nachname', 'strasse' => 'Strasse', 'hausnummer' => 'Hausnummer', 'plz' => 'Plz',
    'ort' => 'Ort', 'liefer_strasse' => 'Lieferadresse Straße', 'liefer_hausnummer' => 'Lieferadresse Hausnummer', 'liefer_plz' => 'Lieferadresse PLZ', 'liefer_ort' => 'Lieferadresse Ort', 'lieferant_name' => 'Lieferant Name', 'lieferant_email' => 'Lieferant E-Mail',
    'lieferant_phone' => 'Lieferant Tel', 'lieferant_need' => 'Wie haben Sie von uns erfahren?', 'message' => 'Nachricht');

$okMessage = 'Ihre Anfrage wurde erfolgreich abgeschickt. Vielen Dank, wir werden uns zeitnah bei Ihnen melden.';


$errorMessage = 'Es gab einen Fehler beim abschicken des Formulars. Bitte probieren Sie es später nocheinmal oder Schreiben Sie uns direk';


// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try {

    if (count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Kontaktformular ist leer');

    $emailText = "Eine neue Nachricht vom Kontaktformular\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        'Bcc:' . $Bcc
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
} // else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

```js
// function for lieferadress

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CheckLiefer2').change(function(){
        if($("#CheckLiefer2").is(':checked')){
            $('#lieferadresse').show();
            $('.lieferadresse_req').prop('required',true);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#lieferadresse').hide();
            $('.lieferadresse_req').prop('required',false);
        }
    });
})

// ajax function for form
$(function () {

    // init the validator
    // validator files are included in the download package
    // otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

    $('#contactForm').validator();


    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contactForm').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact2.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                 {
                    console.log(this);
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contactForm').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contactForm')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Billiger Verschiffen | <?php echo $title;?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<form id="contactForm" class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact2.php" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="controls">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1>Infos zum Auftraggeber</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firma">Firma *</label>
                                    <input id="firma" type="text" name="firma" class="form-control" placeholder="Firma *" required="required" data-error="Firma wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="anrede">Anrede *</label>
                                    <select id="anrede" name="anrede" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Bitte Anrede auswählen.">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
                                        <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="vorname">Firstname *</label>
                                    <input id="vorname" type="text" name="vorname" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitte Vornamen eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Vorname wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nachname">Lastname *</label>
                                    <input id="nachname" type="text" name="nachname" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitte Nachname eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Nachname wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="straße">Straße *</label>
                                    <input id="straße" type="text" name="straße" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitte Straße eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Straße wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="hausnummer">Hausnummer*</label>
                                    <input id="hausnummer" type="text" name="hausnummer" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitte Hausnummer eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Hausnummer wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="plz">PLZ *</label>
                                    <input id="plz" type="text" name="plz" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitte PLZ eingeben *" required="required" data-error="PLZ wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ort">ORT *</label>
                                    <input id="ort" type="text" name="ort" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitte Ort eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Hausnummer wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top:12px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="CheckLiefer">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="CheckLiefer">Diese Lieferadresse verwenden</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="CheckLiefer2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="CheckLiefer2">Eine andere Lieferadresse verwenden</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="lieferadresse" style="display: none; padding-top:30px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1>Lieferadresse</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="liefer_straße">Straße *</label>
                                    <input id="liefer_straße" type="text" name="liefer_straße" class="form-control lieferadresse_req" placeholder="Bitte Straße eingeben *" data-error="Straße wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="liefer_hausnummer">Hausnummer*</label>
                                    <input id="liefer_hausnummer" type="text" name="liefer_hausnummer" class="form-control lieferadresse_req" placeholder="Bitte Hausnummer eingeben *"  data-error="Hausnummer wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="liefer_plz">PLZ *</label>
                                    <input id="liefer_plz" type="text" name="liefer_plz" class="form-control lieferadresse_req" placeholder="Bitte PLZ eingeben *"  data-error="PLZ wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="liefer_ort">ORT *</label>
                                    <input id="liefer_ort" type="text" name="liefer_ort" class="form-control lieferadresse_req" placeholder="Bitte Ort eingeben *" data-error="Hausnummer wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top:30px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1>Buchungsdokumente</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="FileUpload1">Upload für aktuelles Angebot des bisherigen Spediteurs für die geplante Verschiffung</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="FileUpload1" required="required" name="uploaded_file">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="FileUpload2">Upload der Handelsrechnung für zu verschiffende Ware</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="FileUpload2" name="FileUpload2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" style="padding-top:30px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1>Absenderinformationen</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lieferant_name">Name *</label>
                                    <input id="lieferant_name" type="text" name="lieferant_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Name wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lieferant_email">Email *</label>
                                    <input id="lieferant_email" type="email" name="lieferant_email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse eingeben *" required="required" data-error="E-Mail wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lieferant_phone">Phone *</label>
                                    <input id="lieferant_phone" type="text" name="lieferant_phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefonnummer eingeben *" required="required" data-error="Telefonnummer wird benötigt.">
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lieferant_erfahren">Wir haben Sie von uns erfahren? *</label>
                                    <select id="lieferant_erfahren" name="lieferant_need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Bitte eine Antwort auswählen.">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="Sandro">Sandro von Eykels (Youtube-Kanal)</option>
                                        <option value="Google">Google Suche</option>
                                        <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo Suche</option>
                                        <option value="Werbeanzeige">Sonstige Werbeanzeige</option>
                                        <option value="Freunde">Von Bekannten/ Freunden</option>
                                        <option value="Sonstige">Sonstige</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message">Nachricht *</label>
                                    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Nachricht" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Bitte hinterlasse uns eine Nachricht."></textarea>
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Abschicken">
                            </div>
                            <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="messages" style="padding-top:20px;"></div>
                </form>
                </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i already changes path to /uploads/ this also dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on your upload folder.  The user that your web server is running as may not have access to write files to your upload directory.  With FTP or SSH you can change it to 0755 which should let you write your uploads to the upload directory.